# How to run sbt task on make project in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt

I'm working on a scalajs project. My workflow is: make code changes, make project in IntelliJ, go to sbt and run fastOptJS task to produce js file, go to browser and test. I would like to remove the step of manually running fastOptJS task in sbt and make that happen automatically when I make project in IDEA. Is there any way to do that?

UPD: It would be also nice to keep sbt running between fastOptJS calls, cause it takes time for sbt to start.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply start the JavaScript compilation with the `sbt` watch mode.

Select `Run | Edit configurations...` and add a new *SBT Task* by pressing the green plus. In the field "Tasks:" define `~fastOptJS` and then run the new configuration.

[image]

It will compile again whenever you have changed something.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This should be the workaround for your propose, instead of use "Make Project ( Ctrl + F9 )", you can create a run in IDEA and configure an external tool as the image shown, where you can run the fastOptJS task in sbt.

[image]

Comment: Will it keep sbt running between fastOptJS calls? Cause it takes time for sbt to start.

Comment: @Yaroslav no, it will terminate after the external took executed.